# How do I return an error when the error type of a function is different?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am writing a vector class that uses templates so that it can support multiple data types being stored within it. I have a function called *get()* which returns a specific index within the vector.

**MyVector.h**

```
template<class type>
class MyVector {
    /* Stuff to make the vector work with features such as pushing back...*/
    type get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > this->size) {
            /* Make the compiler recognize this as a compile error and return
               an error message of my choice
            */
            return type{};
        }
        return this->data[index];
    }
};
```

My first question here is how do I make the compiler stop and recognize this as an error and fail to compile. In addition to failing to compile, the compiler should print some error message like *Index out of range* or something like that. Is this possible within **C++**?

My second question here is why return type{} actually works (I had to return something, and I just randomly tried ***return type{}***).

In addition, I am trying to use operator overloading so that I can access elements of the vector class with ease. The operator overloading function should return a reference to the element being returned, so that I can change it.

Like *vector[index] = value*.

The following is my function

```
type& operator[](int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > this->size) {
        /* Make the compiler recognize this as a compile error and return
           an error message of my choice
        */
        return type{};
    }
    return this->data[index];
}
```

I have the same question as above, namely, how do I make the compiler fail to compile and print an error message. Also, what am I supposed to return in this situation? Is there any way I can avoid returning altogether?

Comment: Instead of returning an error value, throw an exception

Comment: You can't use compile-time checks for run-time errors.  When the error is detected at run-time `throw` an error as an exception.

Comment: @Eljay I am trying to make this part of a library of sorts... "What if the user doesn't know that they have to catch?" is the problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: If you can't use a throw, you could use an `assert` and terminate the program execution.

Comment: then the uncaught exception would just crash the program. And this exception could be picked by the debugger

Comment: there's also std::optional, that return an object of some type + a boolean, that indicates, if the object is valid or not

Comment: One way to make the user aware is to call the function `at()` instead. By convention `operator[]` usually does not do bounds checking while `at()` does.

Comment: "What if the user doesn't know that they have to catch?"  They'll figure it out the first time they get an uncaught exception.  And you'll have documentation, right?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. It is not possible to determine run time errors at compile time.

Comment: "*I just randomly tried*" ... trial-and-error approach does not work with C++ because instead of an error there's often undefined behavior. For example, `return type{}` in the second example would return a dangling reference. Better to read a good [C++ Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), will save a ton of time.